# How to enable grid field in Acumatica - Journal Transactions screen irrespective of status

Tags: acumatica

Below is the code which I have written to enable fields at grid level in Journal Transaction screen but it is not working. I have tried with automation steps but it also doens't work. Could any one help me out here?

```
protected void Batch_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Batch row = (Batch)e.Row;

    if (row != null)
    {               
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<GLTran.branchID>(Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<GLTran.accountID>(Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<GLTran.subID>(Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<GLTran.refNbr>(Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<GLTran.qty>(Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<GLTran.uOM>(Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<GLTran.curyDebitAmt>(Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Cache, null, false);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetReadOnly<GLTran.curyCreditAmt>(Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Cache, null, false);

    }
}
```

Comment: you want SetEnabled vs SetReadOnly. These fields are enabled by default. Are there access rights or other customizations involved that might be disabling these fields?

Comment: Can you please provide a little more info about your business scenario? For the most part, my concern is that enabled editing for Unposted and Posted Batches can cause issues with Account Balances...